# Unable Connect to ElasticSearch Managed Service

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, kibana

I have deployed an ES Managed service on Azure. I am able to access the Kibana Web app at
http://20.xx.xxx.172:5601/

In the NSG I have opened ports 8080, 5601 and 9200.

[image]

But when tried to run ES query using postman, it is not giving any response? How can we make the setup work?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to tell ElasticSearch to open up publicly, as it only [binds to localhost by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html). In the elasticsearch.yml file, this is done by setting the network.host var:

> network.host: 0.0.0.0

The 0.0.0.0 tells ElasticSearch  that it will allow itself to get contact from the outside world.

With this, I'd like to suggest that you should secure your Kibana & ElasticSearch. Ideally, only expose kibana to the outside world with secure authentication. ElasticSearch should stay unexposed.

Authentication is now free with Kibana since a while. You can check the docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kibana-authentication.html) for your favorite method.

PS: I'm not a security guy, so don't burn me. Just trying to stay, take care.

Comment: How to access the YAML file inside the managed Elasticsearch server?

Comment: I'm not sure about the managed service. There's probably be some security setting for inbound/outbound traffic to "ElasticSearch". From there, you need to allow ElasticSearch to communicate with outside connections.

Or maybe there's a direct way to access the yaml file

Comment: Did it work out for you? If so, please mark the answer as accepted :)